# Copy Profile to New Profile on Windows 10 Machine

Tags: windows-10, user-profiles

I was having many problems with my Windows 10 installation, nothing crippling, but I was unable to use features like Windows Hello I could not change from local to a MS account. I contacted MS and they suggested creating a new profile. I did so and all my problems were solved. What is the best way to copy everything over to the new profile?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is Windows that you are using I would just do it all in Windows file explorer.

Open up two instances of file explorer and put them side by side. Have one showing the old profile and the other showing the new profile. The old profile is probably at C:\Users\OLDUSERNAME and the new is at C:\Users\NEWUSERNAME

Do not drag and drop the profile folder itself but drag and drop most of the contents within it. Drag and drop everything from the old one (Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Pictures, Videos, etc) into the new one EXCEPT for the hidden Appdata folder. The Appdata folder stores many of the settings associated with your profile so moving this folder can cause profile corruption. You do not want to bring any of the Appdata.

So be sure to highlight all of the files/folders that you want and drag and drop them into the profile. To be on the safe side it is always better to copy the files into the new location rather than moving them to ensure that no data is lost.